# In iOS,Navigation show Navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I try to Use Navigation show Navigation,but the transitions animation is From down to up.

```
UIViewController2 * vc2 = [[UIViewController2 alloc] init];
UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];
[self.navigationController showViewController:nav sender:nil];
```

Comment: why would you need to do that? It's quite odd.

Comment: @JLT Because in vc2 is not navigationbar when the scrolla show the navigation bar.

Comment: hmmm maybe I just don't understand the flow I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
SecondViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerB"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```